# When i try to use node app to run the application it does not run on the given port . can someone explain?

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am trying to create an API to generate random names using node and express but the node app won't run
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you’re having is given that you’re trying to require a file that’s not a module (`WifiNames.json`), you either can read it using the `fs` module or change the file extension to `js` and export the json array using `module.export`